# Copy file instantly while Tkinter Program is running

Tags: file, tkinter, copy, python-3.7, instant

I have a little GUI Program that should only get some inputs to use these inputs for a method call.

Therefore I have several tk.Entry objects. Now my method that I want to execute needs a file from my hard disk. I want to scrape it with ElementTree. (I think the file needs to be in the same directory as my .py file? If not please tell me how to use a file from another path). My Idea was to copy that file into the current filepath and then only use a simple call to get access to this file. 
But when I want to copy this file it is getting copied after I close the program and that should not happen. It should instantly copy the file so I can work with it.

Is there a way to refresh my files or do you have another idea?

Thank you and here is my code:

```
from Modules import copy_file
import tkinter as tk


class MainApplication(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        for Frame in (StartPage, SuccessPage):
            page_name = Frame.__name__
            frame = Frame(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    # method to show frames
    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name] #getting our frame from our frames list
        frame.tkraise() #raise it up to the front


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        # Open File Button 
        self.button_open_file = ttk.Button(self, text = "Open File", command = self.get_file_directory).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky="WE")


    def get_file_directory(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("all files","*.*"),("jpeg files","*.jpg")))
        copy_file(filename)


class SuccessPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        # Open File Button 
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text =  "Lab").grid(row=0 column=0, sticky="WE")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = MainApplication().mainloop()



----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Modules.py

from shutil import copy

def copy_file(src):
    destination_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    copy(src, destination_path)
```

Comment: What's the variable `SuccessPage`?Could you show a minimal example?

Comment: Oh im sorry, i will add it. It is just another page in my Application